# Error in Indexing ROS Repository

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ! The pull request for document indexing is merged. But even then, the package information is not displayed on ROS Wiki page !

Wiki page : http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_keyboard_omni3

Details added in distribution.yaml :

teleop_keyboard_omni3:

```
doc:
  type: git
  url: https://github.com/YugAjmera/teleop_keyboard_omni3.git
  version: master
source:
  type: git
  url: https://github.com/YugAjmera/teleop_keyboard_omni3.git
  version: master
status: maintained
```

Can someone tell me what to do to get the Package Summary ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317691/error-in-indexing-ros-repository/) by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your PR ([ros/rosdistro#20480](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/20480)) was merged 4 hours ago.

Doc jobs are only run once every three days.

You'll have to have a little more patience.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) on 2019-03-06**:
Ok! Thank You.